# Maui Shell Flyout IsPresentedChanged event

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, flyout, maui-shell

Xamarin forms to Maui migration question...

The FlyoutPage in XF has the IsPresentedChanged event that fires when the Flyout menu is displayed/hidden.

Is there an equivalent for Maui Shell Flyout? I can't find anything in the docs.

As a supplement I have a ContentView set as the Shell.FlyoutContent and I can accomplish my requirement (amend a property on the ContentView when the Flyout menu becomes visible) via an OnAppearing event on the ContentView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shell doesn't have a such event. But you can detect the [Shell.FlyoutIsPresented Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell.flyoutispresented?view=net-maui-8.0) changed by your custom event.

```
  public AppShell()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      PropertyChanged += Changed;
  }   

  private void Changed(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if(e.PropertyName == "FlyoutIsPresented")
      {
          if(FlyoutIsPresented)
          {

          }else
          {
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. While the property is on the ContentView set to the FlyoutContent I can access this in the AppShell.xaml.cs via "AppShell.Current.FlyoutContent" so can make this work....appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the MVVM Community Toolkit then you can rely on two-way binding and the source generated `OnXXXChanged` / `OnXXXChanging` methods.

In your ViewModel:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
bool _isFlyoutPresented;
```

In your View (XAML):

```xml
<Shell FlyoutIsPresented="{x:Binding IsFlyoutPresented, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now you can react to the changes in your ViewModel:

```cs
partial void OnIsFlyoutPresentedChanging(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

Setting the `IsFlyoutPresented` property will now trigger the flyout. You can tell if it's open by checking the value in `IsFlyoutPresented`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply...much appreciated. I can see how this would work so while I've implemented using @Liyun Zhang - MSFT answer I thank you for sharing. I presume the PropertyChanging event is auto bound to the ObservableProperty then?

Comment: Both answers effectively do the same thing. My answer uses the binding system and the MVVM Community Toolkit `OnXXXChanged`/`OnXXXChanging` methods. Those methods are automatically called before/after the property changes in the generated 'setter' code. It gives you a single place to react to the value changing. Most things in MVVM can be done via binding (my answer) or code behind (the other answer). If you do code behind and you have multiple views (many platforms) then you have to put the code behind in each platform vs. letting the ViewModel handle it on all platforms.